# what are the difference in memory_order_seq_cst with other memory order?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a table to summarize the difference in memory order?
such as which situation to use each memory order

moreover, what is the difference between memory order and (data_cond and future)?

```
is it 
1. memory order is for waiting
2. data_cond is for waiting 
3. future is for doing other thing while waiting
```

Answer (score 2):

Memory orders are used to specify memory ordering in atomic operations. The simplest memory order is `memory_order_seq_cst` which gives you sequential consistency. Other memory models give relaxed momory orderings.

If you want to get an *acquire-release* ordering you are expected to combine: `memory_order_consume`, `memory_order_acquire`, `memory_order_release`, and
`memory_order_acq_rel`.

If you want to get a relaxed ordering you are expected to use `memory_order_relaxed`.

Here is a simple example of using memory ordering to implement a spin-lock mutex:

```
class spinlock_mutex {
private:
  std::atomic_flag f;
public:
  spinlock_mutex() : f(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

  void lock() {
    while (f.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) {}
  }

  void unlock() {
   flag.clear(std::memory_order_release());
  }
};
```

There is data_cond type in C++11. I figure out you may be referring to `std::condition_variable` which is a condition variable to be associated to a mutex.

```
std::mutex m;
std::queue<request> q;
std::condition_variable cv;

void producer() {
  while (more_data()) {
    request r = generate_request();
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
    q.push(r);
    cv.notify_one();
  }
}

void consumer() {
  for (;;) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    cv.wait(l, []{ return !q.empty();});
    request r = q.front();
    l.unlock();
    process_request(r);
    if (is_last(r)) break;
  }
}
```

Finally, a future allows that a thread may return a value to the code section which made the invocation.

```
int main() {
  std::future<int> r = std::async(do_something, 1, 10);
  do_something_else();
  std::cout << “Result= “ << r.get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```